# Equations of motion for double spherical pendulum simply?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

I am attempting to simulate a double spherical pendulum, i.e. a combination of the [spherical pendulum](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/explore/michaelspages/documentation/Spherical) and the double pendulum.

I understand that the equations of motion can be derived via the Lagrangian and the Euler-Lagrange equations. However this method rapidly becomes *very* messy.

Is there an alternate method that could be used to simplify the calculations required?

-UPDATE-

This is an update to specify the Lagrangian of the system as requested in the comments.

We have two spherical pendulums, denoted $1$ and $2$. The lengths of each pendulum $l_1=l_2=1$ whilst the masses $m_1=m_2=1$.

There are two parameters that describe the location of the pendulum mass $\theta$, the angle from the vertical, and $\phi$ the azimuthal angle about the vertical axis. For a diagram [see here](http://physique.unice.fr/sem6/2011-2012/PagesWeb/PT/Pendule/Images/spherical_pendulum.png).

The locations of the masses $r_1 , r_2$ are therefore given by (for a vertical $z$ axis):
$$x_1 = sin(\theta_1)cos(\phi_1)$$
$$y_1 = sin(\theta_1)sin(\phi_1)$$
$$z_1 = -cos(\theta_1)$$

and

$$x_2 = x_1+sin(\theta_2)cos(\phi_2)$$
$$y_2 = y_1+sin(\theta_2)sin(\phi_2)$$
$$z_2 = z_1-cos(\theta_2)$$

The Lagrangian is given by the difference between the kinetic and potential energies $L = E_k -E_p$

$$E_k = \frac{1}{2} \left( \dot{r}_1^2 +\dot{r}_2^2  \right)$$
$$E_p = g (z_1 +z_2)$$

The Lagrangian then follows simply from taking the time derivatives of $r_1$ and $r_2$. (Note that this leads me to a very long and complicated form the Lagrangian)

Comment: I am afraid that this problem actually IS very messy. Traditional way is to use the small amplitude approximation.

Comment: Hi Tom. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: *...this method rapidly becomes very messy.* welcome to physics ;)

Comment: Thanks for all comments. Qmechanic  have read the policy now and so accept your edit :). I am happy to accept these comments as an answer. What is the protocol in this situation? Thanks all

Comment: @Tom If you can't be bothered to go through the derivation of the e.o.m. yourself (it's not *that* tedious), you can do it easily in a program like Mathematica.

Comment: @Tom: Consider to include explicitly the Lagrangian in the post, so that everybody is on the same page on which system you are interested in.

Comment: Are the masses distributed on the members, or concentrated on the nodes?

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of. However if you're fine with considering only small oscillations, then you can replace $\sin \theta$ by $\theta$ and $\cos \theta$ by $1-\frac{\theta^2}{2}$. This might make things simpler although the solution you get will be acceptable for small angles.

Comment: This is explained [here](http://downloads.hindawi.com/journals/ddns/2006/025193.pdf)